# How to externalize DataSource.groovy for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy

I am trying to externalize `Mongodb` configurations in my Grails project.
As configuring in `DataSource.groovy` means, I have to rebuild the WAR file.
I have seen many references for `MYSQL` , Oracle and other Databases. 
Can somebody please tell me how to do that for `MongoDB`?
Thanks in advance.

```
Grails Version :-2.3.4
MongoDB Plugin Version :-3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on `DataSource.groovy` I assume you use Grails 2. If yes, you can use external config to achieve that. See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/guide/conf.html#configExternalized for information how to setup external config. In this file just set options for Mongo like you set them in `DataSource.groovy`

Depending on version of `mongodb` plugin it should be something like:

```
grails {
    mongo {
        host = 'localhost'
        port = 27017
        databaseName = "someDB"
    }
}
```

or

```
grails {
    mongodb {
        host = 'localhost'
        port = 27017
        databaseName = "someDB"
    }
}
```

(difference is `mongo` and `mongodb` in option namespace)

Comment: Thanks. Have edited the question with versions.
I will try this and let you know if it works.